How to add a functionapp slot identity as a user in the azure postgresql database
I would like to add a functionapp slot identity as a user in the database.
However, this function:
SELECT * FROM pgaadauth_create_principal('functionappname/slot/slotname', false, false);

fails with an unexpected error.
The following message is provided:
SQL statement "SECURITY LABEL for "pgaadauth" on role "appname/slot/slotname" is 'aadauth'"

I can add the identity as a database admin via the azure portal, but I don't want to grant it admin rights.

which user you are using to run above query?


I can add the identity as a database admin via the azure portal, but I don't want to grant it admin rights.

If you add your managed identity as Active directory admin, according to the MS document

A service principal or managed identity can act as fully functional Microsoft Entra administrator in Azure Database for PostgreSQL flexible server. This was a limitation in Azure Database for PostgreSQL single server.

So, you can't change the admin rights of managed identity.
I tried to add the managed identity of function app as user, and it got added successfully but for the managed identity it is throwing error as unexpected error occurred while trying to validate user.
Pleases check with Microsoft support for more help and check if any limitation.
